# Rabbitmq multiple bindings between one exchange and one queue

Tags: rabbitmq

I have 1 topic exchange named `test-exchange` and 1 queue named `test-queue`. I have below 2 bindings between the said exchange and queue

[image]

Then I sent a message on exchange `test-exchange` with routing key `test-key`. Checked the queue `test-queue`, only 1 message received. I expected 2 messages as I thought the message will be duplicated on both path. Any idea why this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is intentional. It has nothing to do with RabbitMQ, but rather with AMQP specification:

> A server MUST not deliver the same message more than once to a queue, even if the queue has multiple bindings that match the message.

Source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html

If you want a message to be duplicated, you need to create two separate queues.

However, if you really need those messages to be duplicated within a single queue, a more complex topology might be helpful. For instance, you can bind one exchange to another, and then bind the queue to two separate exchanges, as follows:
[image]
Diagram created with this tool: https://jmcle.github.io/rabbitmq-visualizer/#